# PHPUnit says im not passing argument to parent class method. I am

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a test class that extends an abstract parent class. The parent class extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, it defines some methods that all tests will use.

I'm having an issue calling the parents methods. Phpunit is saying that i'm not providing any arguments to the method but i am.

Here is the child's method

```
public function testEmptyGarbageNullDataDoesntValidate() {
    $rule = new Rule\Between( 1, 10 );
    $this->testNullDataDoesntValidate( $rule );
    // $this->testEmptyDataDoesntValidate( $rule );
    // $this->testGarbageDataDoesntValidate( $rule );
}
```

Here's the parent method

```
public function testNullDataDoesntValidate( \Validator\Rule $rule ) {
    $this->validator->addRule( 'null', $rule );
    $this->assertFalse( $this->validator->validate( array( 'null' => null ) ) );
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Argument 1 passed to BaseRuleTest::testNullDataDoesntValidate() must
>   be an instance of Validator\Rule, none given

It's saying None is given, but its being given. I can go into the child's function and `var_dump( $rule )` and see the data, it's definitely there.

Here's the `var_dump` from within the parent method

```
object(Validator\Rule\Between)#210 (2) {
  ["min_value":protected]=>
  int(1)
  ["max_value":protected]=>
  int(10)
}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the way phpunit works. I'm new to phpunit.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try renaming `testNullDataDoesntValidate` to something that doesn't start with test. Just an idea.

Comment: @jchapa And that's actually the answer, you should post is as one.

Comment: @jchapa - yes, that is the answer, post it and ill accept it.

Comment: @deceze - do you know where in the manual it talks about this?

Comment: @deceze: I have posted my response as an answer. Looking for a man ref too.

Comment: @Galen Well, the manual says *somewhere* that *"all methods starting with `test` will be executed as test case"* (paraphrasing)... Guess why all your tests are being executed! :D

Comment: @deceze - Yeah i completely overlooked the fact that since it extended the class it would run those tests because they started with test. I should've noticed it was running extra tests.  I shouldn't be coding at 4am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renaming `testNullDataDoesntValidate` to something that doesn't start with `test`.

Functions that are actual tests begin with the word "test". See here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Because that makes them actual tests, phpunit calls it without arguments.

Comment: It's not a problem of "being able to call them like ordinary functions", it's a problem of *PHPUnit calling the method as test*, without any arguments of course.

Comment: I completely overlooked the fact that since it extended the class it would run the methods because they started with test.  Sometimes i'm dumb.

Comment: I should've noticed it was running more tests.

Answer (score 2):

> Argument 1 passed to BaseRuleTest::testNullDataDoesntValidate() must be an instance of Validator\Rule, none given

That errors is coming from PHPUnit trying to call that *test* method, not from your code calling that method.

If you had included the stack trace (install xdebug to always see it), that would have been obvious.

Comment: I have xdebug installed, it's not showing stack traces when i run the tests.  Again, im new to unit testing.